# how to initialize methods in a UIViewController inside of a viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

There is a method for creating data. This method needs to be called only once. So currently this is the structure:

```
var dataCreated : Bool? = false



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if dataCreated! == false {
        createData()
        self.dataCreated = true
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to ensure `createData()` method is called only once? Thank you.

Comment: Define "once". Once per instance of this view controller being created? Once each time the app is run? Once for the lifetime of the app being installed?

Comment: Once per instance of this view controller being created

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is only called once per instance of a view controller being created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want `createData` to be called once per instance of your view controller, then using `viewDidLoad` is a good place to call it. Further, since `viewDidLoad` is only called once per instance of the view controller, there is no need for the `dataCreated` property. You can remove that.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createData()
}
```

Another option would be to call `createData` from the `init` method of the view controller. This depends on what `createData` needs to access. If the `createData` method needs access to views and outlets, then you must use `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as expected. You might prefer to compute whether data has been created by checking for its existence rather than tracking a separate Boolean variable. Although this will work too.